Is it possible to avoid type assertion when using spread syntax in an array with generics?
export type NavIconsName =
  | 'home-filled'
  | 'home-regular'
  | 'folder-filled'
  | 'folder-regular';

export interface INavLinkBase<T = {}> {
  linkName: string;
  svgIcon?: ISvgIconProps<T>;
  selectedSvgIcon?: ISvgIconProps<T>;
}

export interface ISvgIconProps<IconType> {
  iconName: IconType;
}

const shouldAddLink = true;
const navLinks: INavLinkBase<NavIconsName>[] = [
  ...(shouldAddLink ? ([
    {
      linkName: 'test4',
      svgIcon: {
        iconName: 'folder-regular'
      }
    }
  ]) as const: []),
  {
    linkName: 'test',
    svgIcon: {
      iconName: 'folder-regular'
    },
    selectedSvgIcon: {
      iconName: 'folder-filled'
    }
  }
];

Another user suggested I can add as const to remedy this, but I'd like to avoid this as well. If I remove this, it complains Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'NavIconsName'.(2322). Is this unavoidable?
I tried setting as const or as INavLinkBase<NavIconsName>[] but I'd like to avoid type assertion if possible.

In your case I would probably pick as const assertion - you are assigning your spread array to a constant with explicit type annotation, so you don't get any drawbacks of that approach.
Viable alternatives:

satisfies constraint
extracting your array to a variable and giving it a type annotation are both

In general, the problem is that Typescript widens string and number constants in object literals.
export type NavIconsName =
  | 'home-filled'
  | 'home-regular'
  | 'folder-filled'
  | 'folder-regular';

const icon0 = {
    iconName: 'folder-regular',
    iconSize: 20
}

type IconType0 = typeof icon0;
// type IconType0 = {
//    iconName: string;
//    iconSize: number;
//}

There are 3 ways to change this:
Type annotation
type Icon = {
  iconName: NavIconsName;
  iconSize: 20 | 40;
}

const icon1: Icon = {
    iconName: 'folder-regular',
    iconSize: 20
}

Pros:

type check against expected type
editor hints

Cons:

precise type information is lost

Const assertion
const icon2 = {
    iconName: 'folder-regular',
    iconSize: 20
} as const;

type IconType2 = typeof icon2;

//type IconType2 = {
//    readonly iconName: "folder-regular";
//    readonly iconSize: 20;
//}

Pros:

precise type information is kept

Cons:

no type check
no editor hints

satisfies constraint
const icon3 = {
    iconName: 'folder-regular',
    iconSize: 20
} satisfies Icon;

type IconType3 = typeof icon3;

//type IconType3 = {
//    iconName: "folder-regular";
//    iconSize: 20;
//}

Pros:

precise type information is kept
type check against expected type
editor hints

